# CSS Transform Property Not Working Properly with Multiple Transforms

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent, css-transforms

I was working on a project where you can adjust the CSS transform property of a div, and I noticed that some combinations of transforms don't work correctly. I am guessing it has something to do with the order of the transforms, but I am not sure. I am also wondering is there a simple way I can make my project work with any combination of transforms?

Here's the code:

```js
function changeDiv(e) {
  var x = e.clientX; // Get mouse x and y
  var y = e.clientY;
  if (/tr/.test($("#mouseX").val())) { // Find the suitable unit using a regex on value of corresponding select tag
    var xUnit = "px"
  } else if (/(sk|ro)/.test($("#mouseX").val())) {
    var xUnit = "deg"
  } else {
    var xUnit = ""
  }
  if (/tr/.test($("#mouseY").val())) {
    var yUnit = "px"
  } else if (/(sk|ro)/.test($("#mouseX").val())) {
    var yUnit = "deg"
  } else {
    var yUnit = ""
  }
  $("#tilt").css("transform", $("#mouseX").val() + "(" + ((x - (window.innerWidth / 2)) / 2) + xUnit + " ) " + $("#mouseY").val() + "(" + ((y - (window.innerHeight / 2)) / 2) + yUnit + " )");
  // Change the div css
}
```

```css
#tilt {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onmousemove="changeDiv(event)">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  Mouse X:
  <select id="mouseX">
    <option value="translateX">translateX()</option>
    <option value="translateY">translateY()</option>
    <option value="scaleX">scaleX()</option>
    <option value="scaleY">scaleY()</option>
    <option value="rotateX">rotateX()</option>
    <option value="rotateY">rotateY()</option>
    <option value="rotateZ">rotateZ()</option>
    <option value="skewX">skewX()</option>
    <option value="skewY">skewY()</option>
  </select>
  Mouse Y:
  <select id="mouseY">
    <option value="translateX">translateX()</option>
    <option value="translateY" selected>translateY()</option>
    <option value="scaleX">scaleX()</option>
    <option value="scaleY">scaleY()</option>
    <option value="rotateX">rotateX()</option>
    <option value="rotateY">rotateY()</option>
    <option value="rotateZ">rotateZ()</option>
    <option value="skewX">skewX()</option>
    <option value="skewY">skewY()</option>
  </select>
  <div id="tilt"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The project is also on my website [here](http://dinod123.neocities.org/tilting.html).

A table of which combinations work is [here](https://goo.gl/hNTjm6).

Comment: In your code, you're checking `$("#mouseX")` in the Y-coordinate part.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle with that bug fixed.](http://jsfiddle.net/4ta8vskj/2/)